# Increase the number of items displayed under the user profiles on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web

Even my old Nokia 3310 could handle more than 5 items per page.*

<sup>* if it had an internet connection.</sup>

It seems the sections under the User profiles on the mobile site are limited to a mere 5 items per page. E.g. the [recent answers page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163863/matt?tab=answers).

In the modern day world with my 480×800 screen resolution, this doesn't even fill the screen.

Any chance the per page limit could be increased?

Comment: Holy crap. My first phone was a Nokia 3310.

Comment: @BoltClock's SNAP!

Comment: Hmmm... I have a new Android phone, fairly large screen (4.5"), and at the default resolution, my "recent answer" page leaves only about 5 mm unused, given the 5 most recent question titles I have answered.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Well that's the point... a little bit of scrolling doesn't go amiss (compare the user pages to the homepage for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the launch of [new mobile design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239378/mobile-web-refresher-part-3) number of [answers per page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/163863/matt?tab=answers&tt=activity&__=1960619266) was increased to 20.

> [image]