# Mobile "view more" for Question and Answers in profile show only chunks of 5

Tags: feature-request, search, mobile-web

1. Go to a profile in mobile
2. scroll to "Answers". You see the first 5 answers (fine!) and then the link "view more".
3. Select that link.
4. Now you see again the first 5 answers, and a link to the next, then the next and so on. This is not very practical: Selecting a link every five entries is too much interaction.

Contrast this with the search results when selecting a user's tag, or issuing a general query: There you get a list of 30 entries that can be smoothly browsed by up/down scrolling.

It would be nice if also Answers/Questions show a list of similar length. Up/down scrolling on mobile devices is one of the things that work very nicely on mobiles.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114897/increase-the-number-of-items-displayed-under-the-user-profiles-on-the-mobile-sit