# Mobile web refresher, part 3

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web, announcements

Here’s the final major installment of the mobile web redesign/refresher. We have also fixed or implemented a <del>minimal</del> large part of the issues and requests mentioned in the [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237518/mobile-web-refresher-part-2) [refresher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher) questions.

## Changes

### Tag list, Badge list and User list

- New list style optimized for vertical scrolling
- Page optimized for human-sized fingers (apparently not everyone is a hobbit)
- New, more usable subnav UX

[image: Tag List]

[image: Badge List]

[image: User List]

---

### User page

- Adopted new subnav and vertical list styles for pretty much all the subsection in the User Summary page
- Equally restyled all the secondary pages (Accounts, Activity, Answers, Badges, Bounties, Favorites, Questions, Reputation, Responses, Tags, Votes)

[image: User Summary Page]

---

## CAPTCHA page (new)

- We now have a mobile CAPTCHA page, previously you would be bounced to the desktop page for maximum pain.

[image: CAPTCHA page]

Send your gratitude to [Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) for the design :-)

This will be the last major iteration for now. We might develop small feature requests off-band, and we will fix bugs as appropriate. (*)

Feedback welcome below!

*<sup>(*) there's no need to repeat feature requests from the other questions as we've already put them on our Trello board.</sup>*

---

*This is now available on the network. You can browse from your phone or click the "mobile" link below to access it.*

Comment: Presumably the accepted status on answers is part of the Trello board then?

Comment: Are those of us stuck with older OSes/browsers going to get fallback images for the various buttons? I don't see any icons (on the top bar, voting etc.) which makes it virtually impossible to use the sites.

Comment: @ChrisF we support 2 versions back. AFAICT all those browsers (and older) support the new images. Our historical stats show that much less than 1 percent of *mobile web* users are affected.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Nice to know I'm in the 1% then ;) I was afraid that was going to be your answer. I suspect it's an OS thing (Android 2.3.something) rather than a browser thing.

Comment: @ChrisF you are using pretty much the only mobile browser that doesn't support it! :-) http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: £%$&£* typical ;) Time to get a new phone I suppose :(

Comment: Is this bug report already on your radar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239237/some-posts-are-partially-hidden-on-the-mobile-website-in-firefox ?

Comment: Is there a chance at getting a better mobile aware chat? Using [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) on mobile is an extremely painful experience for many people compared to the desktop site.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any plan to redesign the chat mobile theme?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the new version on the left or on the right?

Comment: @nhinkle left: old; right: new. Think of before/after wonder hair growth ads ;-)

Comment: Woo, in the 1% :( My Android browser version (2.2.2) isn't even listed on the caniuse.com page.

Comment: @Sklivvz: are issues (such as the lack of relevant numbers on the user pages) still under consideration to be fixed or should we now file new bugs / feature requests? It has been nearly 3 months and nothing has changed; the user page issue is *really annoying*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters they are "by design", but you can open a feature request if you like.

Comment: @Sklivvz: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244758/mobile-web-show-specific-reputation-change-or-vote-edit-count-on-user-lists).

Answer (score 11):

Maybe implement a mobile inline editor for users with full editing privs? It is very useful in the full versions of sites.

Answer (score 9):

The users listing shows only the user total reputation, not the reputation change for the chosen  time period.

So for the Stack Overflow *reputation - week* view, I'd expect to see *640* listed for me, but only the total rep is shown:

[image: users listing]

Comment: You forgot the red hand-drawn circle... I cannot see your point ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderVogt any tips on a free image editor for iPhone then? This post was made on my mobile!

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap.-mark-up.-send./id490505997?mt=8) is pretty good.

Comment: @Unsigned cool! I already am a Skitch for OS X users, didn't know there was a mobile edition.

Comment: Same problem with lists of voters and editors, where the corresponding counts (votes, edits) are not shown at all. Sort of defeats the purpose of the pages. I was about to post this as a bug, but saw you reported it. Then again, it hasn't been fixed, so how to raise awareness now?

Comment: @Behaviour: I directly poked the dev about this.

Comment: @Behaviour: since Sklivvz stated this omission is by design I created a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244758/mobile-web-show-specific-reputation-change-or-vote-edit-count-on-user-lists) to get the functionality back.

Answer (score 4):

When viewing questions for a single tag, that tag's excerpt is now shown under the tag.

[image: Portrait screenshot]

This takes up quite a bit of real estate and, in my opinion, is rather intrusive, especially in landscape mode.

[image: Landscape screenshot]

Since the refresher, I've found the feature requests regarding this, and I can see the reason for it. Honestly, though, if you're regularly viewing questions for a particular tag, you pretty much already know what the tag is all about, and don't need to be reminded on every page.

I'm not suggesting that this feature be removed, just "tidied up". Would it be possible to make this expandable, and collapsed by default? I was thinking the excerpt's first several words and an ellipsis would appear to the right of the tag, so that, collapsed, it would take up no more space than does the section that holds the Tagged Questions, search, and show elements. A trailing down-arrow button, or a "show more" link would then expand it to it's full glory seen in the screenshots above.

Comment: I'd be satisfied _as long as it's still there._ I can, after all, visit a tag's list without actually knowing what that tag is, and want to find out what it is. In fact, that's what I do _when I want to know what it is_ - since that's the normal way to get to a tag's wiki.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234723/259214, point 2 ;-)

Comment: @nicael I'm not saying I want it gone, just rearranged. There's a lot of dead space to the right of the tag; let's use it!

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to see the Hot Network Questions sidebar list integrated into the mobile design somewhere. Perhaps as a sub-item in the logo menu on the top-right, or at the bottom of the main page questions list. As far as I can see, there's no way to get to that list.

Comment: The only way I've found is to hit the SE logo menu before the site has fully loaded. As long as the JS hasn't run yet, it's a link to the HNQ.