# Mobile web: Show specific reputation change or vote / edit count on user lists

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, users, rankings

Like on the full site view, you can list users in the mobile web view. Also like the full site view, you can order users by specific metrics, like reputation gain, by votes or edits. You can even filter by specific time periods, seeing how users rank by week, month, quarter, year or overall on each of those metrics.

Until the [Mobile web refresher, part 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239378/mobile-web-refresher-part-3) update, filtering by time period was actually useful, showing you the change in the chosen metric for the time period. So looking at users by reputation, filtered the current week, would show you the reputation gained so far this week, just like on the full site.

The refresh removed this feature, and I [reported it as a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239414/140890) at the time. Today Sklivvz stated this change was [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/800121):

> they are "by design", but you can open a feature request if you like.

This is that feature request, because just the total reputation shown makes the lists next to useless:

[image: users listing]